# datomic "index creation failed" "merge-db failed"

Tags: database, datomic

After adding a new index in datomic I got this Error.
The very same problem occured on one of my systems some Years ago and is still not fixed:

```
2018-11-27 10:23:37.580 WARN  default    datomic.update - {:message "Index creation failed", :db-id "xxx-8eb416be-ec26-4bff-b4ce-503bb734026b", :pid 29822, :tid 15}
java.io.IOException: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at datomic.external_sort$temp_file_io$reify__5949.make_temp_file(external_sort.clj:22) ~[datomic-transactor-pro-0.9.5656.jar:na]
    at datomic.external_sort$file_system_sorter$fn__6044.invoke(external_sort.clj:113) ~[datomic-transactor-pro-0.9.5656.jar:na]
    at clojure.core$map$fn__5587.invoke(core.clj:2747) ~[clojure-1.9.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40) ~[clojure-1.9.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49) ~[clojure-1.9.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:528) ~[clojure-1.9.0-RC1.jar:na]
```

```
2018-11-27 10:23:37.602 WARN  default    datomic.index - {:message "merge-db failed", :pid 29822, :tid 15}
java.io.IOException: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at datomic.external_sort$temp_file_io$reify__5949.make_temp_file(external_sort.clj:22) ~[datomic-transactor-pro-0.9.5656.jar:na]
    at datomic.external_sort$file_system_sorter$fn__6044.invoke(external_sort.clj:113) ~[datomic-transactor-pro-0.9.5656.jar:na]
```

Seems like datomic not being able to write down some cache for the indexing process.
It crashes always shortly after restart trying to do the indexing job.

Last time this occurred on one of my systems I contacted support @marshall from datomic. With his help I dumped the datebase, grabbed the backup, reduced the amount of data, assigned a lot of ram ... and it worked. This time that's is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the SOLUTION

the transactor indexer ignores the path settings in the config file ("datomic.version" "0.9.5656" and before tested) and tries to save on actual relative file path.

I made the datomic-pro folder accessible and voilà it creates a ..../data directory and indexing works

**in detail:**

in my debian setup i have set the database path to `data-dir=/var/lib/datomic` 
all the db and tmp files are correctly stored in `/var/lib/datomic`
the datomic pro installation is in `/usr/local/share/datomic/datomic-pro-0.9.5656/`
My relative path starting the transactor (via start-stop-daemon) is also `/usr/local/share/datomic/datomic-pro-0.9.5656/`.

indexing works in my case after:

```
 
chown datomic:datomic /usr/local/share/datomic/datomic-pro-0.9.5656/
```

or better

```
mkdir /usr/local/share/datomic/datomic-pro-0.9.5656/data
chown datomic:datomic /usr/local/share/datomic/latest/data
```

you can watch datomic creating a `/usr/local/share/datomic/latest/data/indexer` folder

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey, great job!

Can you clarify what you mean by making datomic-pro folder accessible? Can you give me step by step instructions how to fix this?

Cheers!